# Tap on pageControl to scroll to another view (tap on the dots)

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uipageviewcontroller

I have set up PageViewControll with 2 views. 
I am able to move between the views and the pageControl (Dots) correspond to the correct page- however tapping the dots doesn't scroll to the correct view just yet.

I found few answers on here on how to create the function but was not able to implement is successfully to make it work. 
The code for the page controller is below (without the tap function)
The full code is :

```
func configurePageControl() {
        pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 50,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 50))
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = viewControllerList.count
        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
        self.pageControl.alpha = 0.5
        self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
        self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        self.view.addSubview(pageControl)


    }

        @IBAction func pageControltapped(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let pageControl = sender as? UIPageControl else { return }
        let selectedPage = pageControl.currentPage
        self.setViewControllers([viewControllerList[selectedPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    }
```

thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You need to create IBAction for `pageControl` from which you can detect which dot was tapped.
2. Then, you need to use `setViewControllers(_:direction:animated:completion:)` method to scroll page programmatically.

   ```
   func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController]?, 
         direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection, 
          animated: Bool, 
        completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
   ```

   [Here's the link to documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller/1614087-setviewcontrollers)

**Use following code:**

```
@IBAction func pageControltapped(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let pageControl = sender as? UIPageControl else { return }
    let selectedPage = pageControl.currentPage
    self.setViewControllers([viewControllerList[selectedPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Add target for pageControl to link it with IBAction:**

```
func configurePageControl() {
    //...your code as it is....
    //add following line
    self.pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pageControltapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much- I have been trying to resolve an error- "Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController' to expected argument type '[UIViewController]?'", in the IBAaction.- any idea?

Comment: It is my mistake! `setViewControllers()` method expects array for viewControllers parameter. You can simply solve it by replacing `viewControllerList[selectedPage]` with `[viewControllerList[selectedPage]]. I've also updated my code for you.

Comment: -Errors are gone but it is still not working unfortunately... I am not sure what I am leaving out- I will add the full code above maybe that will help in solving it

Comment: It is because you need to link `pageControltapped()` method with `pageControl`. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I approved it and thank you so much! i really appreciate your patience and help with this!!  I don't have enough reputations for the upvote to show haha :) but its recording them.

Comment: Listening for `touchUpInside` can lead to the `pageControltapped` called before the value is changed.
Using `valueChanged` is better, as it will be called on each value change basically.