# Is it possible to go to the specific page with PageControl Dots?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I face with a problem about UIPageControl dots. For instance, I made a banner with scrollview and I would like to travel in banner items  by clicking dots of page control added below banner scroll view, but I couldn't find any proper option to go to the specific item by touching related page control dot.

Ex. There are 5 banner items and naturally 5 page control dots. Initially it stars from beginning and continues to the right one after another, how can I directly go to the 3. item by clicking 3. dot?

[My banner and pagecontrol dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWJbu.png)

This is my code for changing banner item with scrolling in scroll view:

pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pageControlTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

```
   @objc func pageControlTapped(sender: UIPageControl) {
        let nextPage = self.pageControl.currentPage + 1
        let newPage = nextPage < self.pageControl.numberOfPages ? nextPage : 0
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: newPage, section: 0)
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55405731/tap-on-pagecontrol-to-scroll-to-another-view-tap-on-the-dots

Comment: `UIPageControl` is designed to increment or decrement the `.currentPage`. It's done that way because the "dots" are too small to tap individually. If you want to do that, the best bet is to create your own "page dots control" view.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use the "valueChanged" event instead of "touchUpInside" for pageControl.

Example:

```
pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pageControlTapped(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

@objc func pageControlTapped(sender: UIPageControl) {
    
     let nextPage = sender.currentPage
     let indexPath = IndexPath(row: nextPage, section: 0)
     self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
}
```